# Unit Testing Web Api Controller that uses IHttpActionResult and ado.net

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to carry out some unit tests on my API Controller however I'm having issues since it is using IHttpActionResult and my actual data is called from a database (Azure).

Here's a sample of a simple Get by id method

```
// GET: api/RoundOnesApi/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(RoundOne))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetRoundOne(int id)
    {
        RoundOne roundOne = db.RoundOnes.Find(id);
        if (roundOne == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(roundOne);
    }
```

I then tried to make a unit test to test this.

```
 public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();


        //arrange

        var controller = new RoundOnesApiController();

        //act

        var actionResult = controller.GetRoundOne(1); //1

        //assert

        var response = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<RoundOne>; //RoundOne is my model class

        Assert.IsNotNull(response);

        Assert.AreEqual(1, response.Content.Id);
```

GetRoundOne(1) contains a database entry of a football teams information. Since this is not null I assumed it would pass.

By the way I'm just looking to do a general Unit Test to see if GetRoundOne(1) can be tested against actually existing. Once it passes that's all I need.

Exception:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Assert.IsNotNull failed. 
  Source=Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.HandleFailure(String assertionName, String message)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.IsNotNull(Object value)
       at MyUnitTestProject.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in c:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UefaServiceV9\MyUnitTestProject\UnitTest1.cs:line 46
  InnerException:
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: When I run it the test fails. I doesn't seem to be picking up controller.GetRoundOne(1). @JeroenVannevel

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Assert.IsNotNull failed.

Comment: For other tests it gave an entity framework exception.

Comment: Right. What exception? You'll need to do some basic debugging if you want me to help you.

Comment: Added to end of question. Thanks

Comment: And you cut off the important part. I want to know the exception thrown by Entity Framework.